# how to make the justify content work in a fixed position

Tags: html, css

I've made this navigation bar but I can't get it to look the way I want it to look

i would like the logo to be separated from the navigation elements but they do not move when I place a position fixed. The logo on the left side and the navigation elements on the right side with a space-between

tried to make the header with fixed position and then enclose the elements in a div to separate them but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you please add some code to your question you can do this by pasting it in then selecting all the code then press ctrl K

Answer (score 0):

If you share your code, I may be able to help more, but as an idea. You could have your logo and then the navigation elements in a ul like the following, therefore you are creating space between the ul and the image but the navigation elements are spaced however you want:

```
<nav class="navbar">
      <img src="logo" />
      <ul :class="nav-menu" >
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href='#'>thing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href='#'>another thing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href='#'>Sign Out</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

```
.navbar {
  min-height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 24px;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 60px;
}

img {
  // image styling
}
```